# Angular bind class of element to element focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my following angular application, I have multiple rows of `myelement` (angular directive wrapper over `input` tag). At a time I need to focus/select/highlight one of it, `.selected` class in the styles does that.

In following application, everything works fine except focus to the `input` tag, which needs to be bounded by the css class `selected`. I.E. whatever element has class `selected` the corresponding `input` tag should be focused . How can I acieve that ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 600px;
    }
    .notebook {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .cell {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .selected {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: green;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-left-width: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ListController as listctrl" class="notebook">

  <div class="container">
    <myelement ng-repeat="i in listctrl.list"
        ng-click="listctrl.selected = $index"
        ng-class="{selected : listctrl.selected === $index}"
        class="cell"></myelement>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .controller('ListController', function($scope) {
    var listctrl = this;
    listctrl.list = [];
    listctrl.selected = 0;

    listctrl.addCell = function() {
      var x = listctrl.list.length;
      listctrl.list.push(x);
      listctrl.selected = listctrl.list.length - 1;
    }

    listctrl.addCell();

    $scope.$on('add', function (event, message) {
      $scope.$apply(listctrl.addCell);
    });

    $scope.$on('keyUp', function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        listctrl.selected = listctrl.selected - 1;
      });
    });

    $scope.$on('keyDown', function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        listctrl.selected = listctrl.selected + 1;
      });
    });
  })
  .directive('myelement', function($rootScope){

    return {
      template: '<input style="width: 95%"></input>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var inputTag = element[0].children[0];
        inputTag.focus();

        element.on('keydown', function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('add');
          } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keyUp');
          } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keyDown');
          }
        });
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {

      }
    };
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't ng-class="{selected : listctrl.selected === $index}" have a "?" in between selected and listctrl.selected since it's a ternary? Or am I reading it wrong.

Comment: @Dream_Cap it's not a ternary, just an object literal

Comment: Can you not use something like `element.hasClass('selected') && inputTag.focus()`? You may need to set your directive's `priority` to something greater than `0` so its post-link function runs after `ngClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following example. It uses the now recommended `component` feature of AngularJS (since v1.5). The example is very simple so you can easily understand what is happening and how to apply it in your project.

**JavaScript**

```js
class MainController {

    constructor() {
        this.focused = true;
    }

}

class MyElementController {

    constructor($element) {
        this.$element = $element;
    }

    $onChanges(changes) {
        if (changes.focused.currentValue === true) {
            this.$element[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        }
    }

}

const myElementComponent = {
    bindings: {
        focused: '<'
    },
    controller: MyElementController,
    template: `<input type="text">`
};

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .component('myElement', myElementComponent);
```

**HTML**

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <my-element focused="vm.focused"></my-element>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
 var elementComponent = {
bindings:{
     selected:'<'
  },
  controller:function($element){
     this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
       if(changes.selected.currentValue){
         $element[0].getElementsByClassName('textName')[0].focus()
       }
    }
  },
  template:'<input type="text" class="textName"  style="margin:4px">'
};

var controller = function(){
   this.list = [1];
   this.selected = 1
   this.add = function(){
     var length = this.list.length ;
      this.list.push(length + 1);
      this.selected = length + 1;
   }
};


angular.module('app', [])
       .component('element', elementComponent)
       .controller('appCtrl', controller);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as vm" >
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
  <button ng-click="vm.add()">Add New Cell</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.list"  >
    <element selected="item == vm.selected"  ng-click="vm.selected = item"></element>
  </div>
  Selected Element : {{vm.selected}}
</body>
</html>
```

This might fill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

on every key up/done, check the class, and use focus(), blur() to change input states. in case of tab press, preventDefault()

```js
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .controller('ListController', function($scope) {
    var listctrl = this;
    listctrl.list = ['1','2','3'];
    listctrl.selected = 0;

    listctrl.addCell = function() {
      var x = listctrl.list.length;
      listctrl.list.push(x);
      listctrl.selected = listctrl.list.length - 1;
    }

    listctrl.addCell();

    $scope.$on('add', function (event, message) {
      $scope.$apply(listctrl.addCell);
    });

    $scope.$on('keyUp', function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        listctrl.selected = listctrl.selected - 1;
      });
    });

    $scope.$on('keyDown', function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        listctrl.selected = listctrl.selected + 1;
      });
    });
  })
  .directive('myelement', function($rootScope){
    return {
      template: '<input style="width: 95%"></input>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var inputTag = element[0].children[0];
        var updateFocues = function(element) {
          if(element[0].className.indexOf('selected') !== -1) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              inputTag.focus()
            });
          } else {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              inputTag.blur()
            });
          }    
        }

        element.on('keydown', function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('add');
          } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keyUp');
          } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keyDown');
          }else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
        

        scope.$on('keyUp', function() {
          updateFocues(element)
        })
        scope.$on('keyDown', function() {
          updateFocues(element)
        })
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {

      }
    };
  })
```

```css
 .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 600px;
    }
    .notebook {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .cell {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .selected {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: green;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-left-width: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ListController as listctrl" class="notebook">

  <div class="container">
    <myelement ng-repeat="i in listctrl.list"
        ng-click="listctrl.selected = $index"
        ng-class="{selected : listctrl.selected === $index}"
        class="cell"></myelement>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use css instead (most likely it will fit your needs). Adding extra JS code to support simple behaviours is not a good practice.

`:focus` selector [explained on W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

E.g.

```
myelement input:focus {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 5px;
}
```